# Upgraded to Mavericks, C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: c, ruby, gcc

Upgrading to Mavericks, I *appear* to have broken my Ruby on Rails development environment, which requires ruby 1.9.3 because of various gem dependencies. Within that app directory, I'm trying to reinstall ruby 1.9.3-p547:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p547
```

I then get an error:

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/dsfaulkenberry/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Looking at the config.log file (~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p547/config.log), I see:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/cloog-ppl015/lib/libcloog.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/gcc46/4.6.4/gcc/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0/4.6.4/cc1
  Reason: image not found
```

I can see that other people have encountered issues vis-à-vis upgrading to Mavericks and having c compiler issues, but I can't find any referencing this specific library or what I should do (reinstall gcc? is that even a thing I can do?)

Many solutions mention accepting an XCode license agreement, which I have done, and the problem persists.

Comment: `/usr/local/Cellar/` and `/usr/local/opt/` suggest to me that you have at least two third-party package managers involved.  I would try using those to *uninstall* all versions of gcc that they know about, and then see if the XCode command line tools work.  This question would probably get better answers on Super User.

Comment: For my upgrade, `homebrew` got very confused and could not find libraries it already had, and would not upgrade them without first removing each one. This was a major problem with the dependencies. I ended up removing Homebrew entirely and then re-installing it and all the individual packages.

Comment: Thanks, Zack. I don't know of any package manager I'm using besides homebrew, and uninstalling gcc through homebrew didn't fix the problem. As you suggest, I'll post this on Super User.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling gcc46 solved the issue for me:

```
brew uninstall gcc46 && brew install gcc46
```